# Do I need to delete the bitbucket repo and create it again if I ran convert?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Imagine I have a mercurial repo hosted on bitbucket, and I accidentally commited & pushed some binary files. I know I could run convert on the repo, and exclude those files, leaving me with the repo in a better state. Do I need to delete the entire bitbucket repo and create it again, or I could somehow do a force push, and have mercurial deal with it?

Comment: Not a direct answer to the problem, but a related answer to help anyone opening this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865076/how-can-i-prune-branches-with-cloning-in-mercurial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run `convert` and then try to push the repo, I get an error saying the repositories are unrelated. So, I guess, the repo needs reuploading.

Answer (score 3):

If there's an option to strip revisions, you can simply do that. However, in any case, anyone who has pulled from your repository since you committed the files will have to re-clone.

Comment: Yes, but the commits are not the latest ones. If I run strip, all following commits are lost.

Comment: Maybe you can save the following commits as patches, and reapply them after the strip?

Comment: oh, then you want to use the rebase extension for mercurial. rebase the following good changes onto the previous good change. This changes history though, so you will probably need to reupload the repository

http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the `backout` command which reverts the effect of an earlier changeset?  See more [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Backout).  You can backout the changeset in question which will force a merge of later changesets, thus removing what you no longer want.  It will still be part of history, though.